# Open Terminal to a Specific Directory

Tags: terminal

On Windows I can Shift Right-click in a folder and I am presented with the option to Open a Command Window Here. Is there a way I can do this on my MacBook Air? Or, do I need to open the terminal manually, and then cd to the destination folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on a Mac by typing `cd` and then just dragging the folder from Finder into the terminal and typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.